# How can I edit the Yaru GNOME theme?

Tags: themes

I use Ubuntu 20.04.2, I found the "themes" folder and inside of it the "yaru-dark" folder, but I can't find the things I want to edit in the folder, like the close window button, and the program headbar. Can someone help me with this?